# using two versions of DB2 drivers at the same time?

Tags: java, spring, db2, datasource

I need to use 2 version of `DB2Driver` for my application. I am using spring to define `dataSources`. The path of two `Libs` are the same, the first `dataSource` needs driver version2 and second one needs version3. Is there any way to solve this problem?

```
  <bean id="DataSource2" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="yyy"/>
    <property name="username" value="yyy"/>
    <property name="password" value="yyy"/>
</bean>

<bean id="DataSource2" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="xxx"/>
    <property name="username" value="xxx"/>
    <property name="password" value="xxx"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="100"/>
    <property name="maxIdle" value="10"/>
    <property name="minIdle" value="1"/>
    <property name="maxWait" value="3000"/>
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
    <property name="testOnReturn" value="false"/>
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="10000"/>
    <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="50"/>
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="10000"/>
    <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Obviously you cannot load two different versions of the same class simultaneously, unless you run two different JVMs.

Comment: but I need to do that, I can connect to one of my servers just with version2 and the second one needs version3

Comment: If you want to do something that's impossible, the best course of action is to find an alternative approach.

Comment: @zara-90  Explain *why* you think you need to use in a single-application two different versions of a Db2-driver.  Also clarify what you mean by "driver version", give exact details. Because your question does not make sense in its original form.

Comment: ok let me explain, this is a big application and in past they have used getBytes to get string in retrieving string data from server A(we can't change them). our DBA told that we have to use driver v2 of db2 because of that and in the same time the server B is updated and we have to use v3 for connecting. so I don't know what to do.

Comment: @mao do you have any idea about this?

Comment: You have not answered my question "what you do mean by driver version".  There is no such thing as "driver version 2". There is a Type-2 driver, and a Type-4 driver (note: TYPE not version), and there is a JDBC 3.0 specification and a JDBC 4.0 specification.  Different driver-versions implement Type-2 and Type-4 and JDBC 3.0 and JDBC 4.0.  Explain your environment components more accurately.

Comment: ( I am assuming that you are not using Db2 version 8.x drivers , from more than 15 years ago, which did have JDBC 3.0 specification implementations in IBM drivers with versions like 2.xx.yy).

Comment: @mao this is what I am using: db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar and db2jcc_license_cu.jar  in version 2 and 3.